# Detect radio form value set

Tags: php, forms

I have a page which has a form, and I want to keep the posted values in there. I've worked out how to do that with a text input, but I havne't worked out how to do it with the radio button:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $colour = $_POST['colour'];
    }
?>
    <html>
        <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['name']); }?>">
           <input name="colour" type="radio" value="0">Red<br>
    <input name="colour" type="radio" value="1">Blue<br>
    <input name="colour" type="radio" value="2">Green<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    ...
```

How am I supposed to set the radio field, do I really have to have an isset on each radio option?

Comment: You seem worried of the amounts of if statements in your form... If your form is going to be bigger, you might want to think about automating some parts to make your life easier. E.g. you could store your form input name and values in an array, loop through and set the name as a variable with either a value that exists, or an empty string. So will not get notice errors that variables have not been set. You could just do this value="<?php echo $name; ?>" instead

Answer (score 3):

Easy answer: yes.

If you do it that way, you will need to set the radio button to "checked" in each `<input>` tag by testing if the values match.

```php
$colour = isset($_POST['colour']) ? $_POST['colour'] : -1;

<input name="colour" type="radio" value="0" <?php if ($colour == 0) echo "checked" ?> >Red<br>
<input name="colour" type="radio" value="1" <?php if ($colour == 1) echo "checked" ?> >Green<br>
<input name="colour" type="radio" value="2" <?php if ($colour == 2) echo "checked" ?> >Blue<br>
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what I did wrong but it doesn't seem to keep the value, but it also doesnt error either? This is what I tried https://gist.github.com/hiven/2c29ebd6ee67915817c02e6caa498ef8

Comment: My mistake: use `checked` instead of `selected`. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the many ways to automate the checking of things in your form. It prevents all the php tags you need to declare otherwise and helps to keep forms manageable.

```
$formArray = [
    'name',
    'color'
];

$optionCoices = [
    'color'=>[
        '0'=>'Red',
        '1'=>'Green',
        '2'=>'Blue',
    ]
];
$postArray = array_fill_keys($formArray,''); // prevent notices since all keys are set to empty string

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // check if $_POST keys are set or set empty string 
    foreach($formArray as $key) {

        $postArray[$key] = isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : '';

    }

}

$form = '';
$form .= '<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="'.$postArray['name'].'">';
// loop through option set and check if value is set in $postArray['color'] 
foreach($optionCoices['color'] as $choice=>$color) {
    $form .= '<input name="color" type="radio" value="'.$choice.'" '.($postArray['color'] === (string)$choice ? ' checked="checked" ' : '').'>'.$color.'<br>';
}
$form .= '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>';

echo $form;
```